# How to save and echo symbol-to-symbol data in database

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, special-characters

I have a simple form with textarea
For example:

```
<textarea name="script"></textarea>
```

From this form I try to save data in MYSQL database. But there is a javascript data. Yes, I try to save full script in database, and then echo it on page. 
So, I have many special chars, quotes,slashes etc.

For Example, there is such part:

```
replace(/"/g,"&quot;");
```

When first time script added in DB - all fine, but when I edit it `&quot` transforms in `"`.

Is there any way to save and edit such data keeping each character?

---

Update: How to send through the POST that?:

```
<textarea name="script">&quot;</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlentities()` & `html_entity_decode()` for store in database.

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll "walk" the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

Comment: it's look like work, but don't. The core problem seems in textarea, when I echo data from DB first time all data is right:
`<textarea name="code">replace(/"/g,"&quot;");</textarea>`
but when i submit form again, `&quot` transforms in `"`.

Comment: why you use `replace` function there

Comment: please give your `php` code for `storing` and `retriving` data from `database`.It will help me to figure out and go for testing it.@Tahiaji

Comment: Last version is
write data:
`mysql_query("UPDATE FOTtable SET value='".base64_encode(htmlentities($value))."' WHERE object='".$object."'");`
and read data:
`html_entity_decode(base64_decode($this->read_one("SELECT value FROM FOTtable WHERE object = '".$object."'")));`